# Either system tray icons or unity-control-center icons disappear - how can I have both?

Tags: unity, 18.04, system-tray, xdg, unity-control-center

*Note: I'm using Unity desktop on 18.04.*

First, most of the icons in `unity-control-center` are missing after I installed then uninstalled `mate-desktop` and `caja`.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried reinstalling all of the installed `unity*` packages, still no result.

I resolved the problem by removing `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` from my `.profile` file and rebooting, however it leads to *some applications' tray icons not appearing*, for example the one for Discord, which I use frequently. Re-inserting that line resolved Discord's system tray, but then the Control Center problem comes back.

Question: How do I resolve these issues at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve it myself by doing a workaround via `alacarte` for each problematic applications;

1. Open up `alacarte` and navigate to your application (you can manually edit, but make sure to know what to do. Using `alacarte` is the safe way)
2. Add this string before the actual command: `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity`
3. Save, and close
4. (Optional) Manually modify `~/.config/autostart/*.desktop` of your application and add the same string after `Exec=` if that still happens.
5. Comment out/delete `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` from your `.profile`

It appears that adding that line to `.profile` causes a bug on Unity in 18.04.